# Bourbon Neat @include row(table) function

Tags: bourbon, neat

Please help.

I'm using Bourbon Neat 1.7 and trying to add and display a second row.
All the info currently displayed shows on one line, should be 2 lines.
My plan is to attach a record set and display the records, line by line.

My scss code

```
.third {
    @include outer-container;
    background-color: #afa;

    .alpha3 {
        @include fill-parent();
        @include row(table);
        margin-bottom: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: #aaf;

        .aside3 {
            @include span-columns(4);
            @include pad();
            border: 1px solid black;
            background-color: #faa;
        }

        .article3 {
            @include span-columns(8);
            @include pad();
            @include reset-display;
            background-color: #faa;
        }
    }
}
```

HTML code

```
<div class="third">
    <p>div class third  </p>
    <div class ="alpha3">
        <div class ="aside3">
            <p>1st Col 1st row </p>
        </div>
        <div class ="article3">
            <p>2nd Col 1st row</p>
        </div>
        <div class ="aside3">
            <p>1st Col 2nd row</p>
        </div>
        <div class ="article3">
            <p>2nd Col 2nd row</p>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `table` display, the row element becomes a table (in this case `.alpha3`), effectively trying to fit all its children without wrapping (tables don't wrap).

You should create an additional `.alpha3` element to host the second row.

```html
<div class="third">
  <p>div class third</p>
  <div class ="alpha3">
     <div class ="aside3"><p>1st Col 1st row </p></div>
     <div class ="article3"><p>2nd Col 1st row</p></div>
  </div>

  <div class ="alpha3">
    <div class ="aside3"><p>1st Col 2nd row </p></div>
    <div class ="article3"><p>2nd Col 2nd row</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```